# Sending events between ui-router states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have an AngularJS application where views will `$broadcast` a "context changed" event to tell its children (`ng-include`s with controllers and directives, all with their child scopes) about what's going on in the parent view. Now I'm [refactoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987149/embedding-angularjs-view) this using *ui-router*, so that there'll be a parent state (non-abstract) and child state.

The parent still happily `$broadcast`ing its "context changed" events, but the child state never gets them. That not entirely surprises me, since scopes are not inherited with *ui-router*, but it is yet a problem for me. What would be a good pattern for such communication between states? Can we leverage off of the fact that there is an existing parent-child relationship between the states that I'm trying to connect? Could I use a service, then how can a service `$broadcast` events (as `$broadcast` is a scope method and the service doesn't have a specific scope).

I have tried calling `$rootScope.$broadcast` (instead of `$scope.$broadcast`) to no avail. I'm just not sure if the `$rootScope` is a shared scope, or what I actually expect that it is just a common definition (like class inheritance).

---

I'm starting to understand better the consequences of calling `$rootScope.$broadcast`. It will notify *the world*. I had some check on `event.targetScope` (probably to make sure that a controller would not notify itself). Now I have the check removed I am getting messages, but unfortunately too many of them (from controllers in a totally different place in the hierarchy). I only want the parent to notify its children. When I used `ng-include` that meant parent scope versus child scope. Now I'm using *ui-router* I would like that to work with parent state (controller) and child state (controller) but **I do not know how to do that**.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with ui-router but I can't think of any reason $rootScope.$broadcast wouldn't be picked up by any scope in your app.

Comment: $rootScope $broadcast should work. The only reason such events are not caught is when the event is raise even before the child view are loaded.

Comment: @Chandermani I've thought about that as well, so I'm trying to (re-)send my event upon `$stateChangeSuccess`, but it never reaches the child. The child immediately after receives its own `$stateChangeSuccess`, so it's there, the parts are moving.

Comment: I got around something like this by creating an events service. Whenever I wanted to "emit" something, I'd save it to a variable in the service. Then the new view would immediately check the service upon loading for any events waiting. I normally use $rootScope.$emit and $broadcast when communicating between two controllers/views that are loaded at the same time. I may have a plunker showing this method if you're interested.

Comment: @Sharondio Thank you. If you're saying you have more to share on how to use the AngularJS eventing system to achieve this (so, exactly what I'm currently failing at) I would be very interested to see more of that. That would be my first choice of approach at this point. If you're saying you created an events service with its own listeners being managed and doing callbacks on those listeners, I think I can craft something like that myself, as a "fallback approach".

Comment: What @Chandermani is saying is probably the case. It's a race condition. Your event is firing, but your view and controller aren't loaded in time to catch it. I went with a service because I knew that I'd need to wait until my new view and controller were loaded to retrieve the event.

Although now you have me thinking. Perhaps what you need is an "Event Queue Service" that can queue up $rootScope events, hold them for a specified time for new controllers to grab, and then clear them? I'm totally spitballing here though.

Comment: @Sharondio Yes, it appears there's some funky stuff going on. When I do `Ctrl`-`F5` on the child state URL, the event is coming in (*good*). When I browse to the parent, then click on the link to go to the child state, it isn't (*bad*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth I want to share the solution to the problem. I doubt the value of this solution because I'm still stuck with some question marks. I fail at a good root cause analysis because I don't have enough insights in the inner workings of `$scope.$broadcast` and *ui-router*, and a lack of understanding of how `$rootScope` is inherited.

There are two separate concepts at play here:

- Parent/child relations of scopes
- Parent/child states

[Per the *ui-router* documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#what-do-child-states-inherit-from-parent-states):

> Nothing else [than resolved dependencies and custom data properties] is inherited (no controllers, templates, url, etc).

Hence the expectation (see comments below the original question) that `$broadcast` will only work if done from `$rootScope`. This, however, cannot be collaborated with my now working implementation.

In any case, my problem seems to have been caused by firing the event (from parent's to child state's controller) too soon, on `$stateChangeSuccess`. When I fire on `$viewContentLoaded` the child will receive it. Note the `$scope.$broadcast`; not `$rootScope`.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    $scope.$broadcast("contextChanged", $scope._fullContext);
})
```

Then all I had left to do is take care of some inadvertent events, fired from the wrong place in the hierarchy or at the wrong time, possible all due to this not being the best-suited design to begin with. I fixed it with some fuzzy logic.

---

One tip for the next gal or guy: be sure to test both these cases:

- User browses to `/parent-state`, then changes state to `/parent-state/child-state`
- User browses immediately to `/parent-state/child-state`

I've often cheered too soon because of this :)

Comment: Thank you for your tip! Its a must !